# Presentational Component continuously rerenders

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

EDIT: I found the problem. It is in the third component code I posted. I am trying to call goToBook and selectBook. So when a user clicks on a book to within the project, it will go to history and pass the user to the route. If the user goes directly to a route, I want to call goToBook directly, so I check if props has selectBook as undefined, if it is, :

```
componentDidUpdate(){//wondering if I should do this inside compoentWillRecieveProps???
    const { match: { params } } = this.props;
    //console.log(this.props.selectBook)
    if(typeof this.props.selectBook !== 'undefined'){
        if(this.state.changedItem !== this.props.goToBook ){
            this.props.selectBook(params.bookID);
            //this.setState({changedItem: params.bookID}); Want to change state here, but cannot do this because I am in componentDidUpdate
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is if I uncomment the console, it runs continuously because it sees selectBook constantly being called. So I need to somehow check the selectBook prop and make sure it is not changing. Any help on this would be appreciated.

---ORIGINAL MESSAGE--- So I have the following code:

```
class ArrayList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {

        };
        this.createListItem = this.createListItem.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.getCollection = this.getCollection.bind(this);
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <ul className="user-list">
                {this.props.items.map(this.createListItem)}
            </ul>
        );
    }
    createListItem(item) {
        if(item.id){
            return (
                <li key={item.id }>
                    {item.name}
                    {this.props.isEditing ? <Button className="deleteMe" onClick={this.handleDelete(this, item)}>Delete</Button> :''}
                </li>
            );
        }else if(item.AwardKey) {
            return (
                <li key={item.AwardKey }>
                    {item.Award}{item.AwardYear?'-':''}{item.AwardYear}
                    {this.props.isEditing ? <Button className="deleteMe" onClick={this.handleDelete(this, item)}>Delete</Button> :''}
                </li>
            );
        }else if(item.RelBookUseInKey) {
            return (
                <li key={item.RelBookUseInKey }>
                    {this.getCollection(item.CollectionForUseInKey)}{item.CollectionNumber?'-':''}{item.CollectionNumber}{item.Rating?'-':''}{item.Rating}{item.RelBookUseInKey}
                    {this.props.isEditing ? <Button className="deleteMe" onClick={this.handleDelete(this, item)}>Delete</Button> :''}
                </li>
            );
        }else if(item.RelBookDoNotUseInKey){
            return (
                <li key={item.RelBookDoNotUseInKey }>
                    {this.getCollection(item.CollectionForUseInKey)}{item.CollectionNumber && item.item.CollectionForUseInKey?'-':''}{item.CollectionNumber}{item.Rating?'-':''}{item.Rating}{item.RelBookDoNotUseInKey}
                    {this.props.isEditing ? <Button className="deleteMe" onClick={this.handleDelete(this, item)}>Delete</Button> :''}
                </li>
            );
        }
    }
    getCollection(collectionVal){
        if(!collectionVal) return '';
        let obj = this.props.collection.find((x)=>{
            return x.value === collectionVal
        });
        return obj.label;
    }

    handleDelete(e){
        if(this.props.handleDelete) {
            this.props.handleDelete(e);
        }
    }
}export default ArrayList;
```

And this presentational component continually renders and doesn't stop. I know this because I put a console.log in front of my render and it runs continuously, slowing down my processor. Is there a way to get a presentational component to only render when props change? I thought that was the point of react/redux. I think I may have something set up wrong with this component. Like the redux workflow may be updating something that is triggering this component to rerender. So I was wondering if the lifecycle of this component is dependent on its parent data to change?

A little about what this component is trying to do: I want to have an array passed to it and based on the contents of the array create a different type of array builder. Some of the array builders have different types of form elements to add different items to the array. 
Here is the parent component:

```
class ArrayValuesEdit extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            displayText: '',
            displayObj:{},
            displayArray:[],
            isEditing: false,
            newItem:0,
            checkProps:false,
            entryType: 'singleText'

        };
        this.onClickEdit = this.onClickEdit.bind(this);
        this.handleSingleSaveEdit = this.handleSingleSaveEdit.bind(this);
        this.handleAwardSaveEdit = this.handleAwardSaveEdit.bind(this);
        this.handleUseInSaveEdit = this.handleUseInSaveEdit.bind(this);
        this.handleDoNotSaveEdit = this.handleDoNotSaveEdit.bind(this);
        this.handleTextChanged = this.handleTextChanged.bind(this);
        this.handleMultipleTextChanged = this.handleMultipleTextChanged.bind(this);
        this.handleKeyPress = this.handleKeyPress.bind(this);
        this.renderList = this.renderList.bind(this);
        this.onSelectionHandle = this.onSelectionHandle.bind(this);
        this.bindSelectionHandle = this.bindSelectionHandle.bind(this);
        this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this);
        this.drawEntryType = this.drawEntryType.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        if(typeof this.props.display !== 'undefined' && typeof this.props.displayArray !== 'undefined'){

            let result = this.props.options.find(x => x.value === this.props.val);
            const displayText = result.text;
            this.setState( {displayText} );
        }
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        // You don't have to do this check first, but it can help prevent an unneeded render
        if (nextProps.displayArray !== this.state.displayArray && !this.state.checkProps) {
            this.setState({ displayArray: nextProps.displayArray, isEditingAll: nextProps.isEditingAll, readOnly: nextProps.readOnly, checkProps: true });
        }
        if (nextProps.entryType !== this.state.entryType)this.setState({entryType: nextProps.entryType});
    }
    onClickEdit(){
        this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
    }
    handleUseInSaveEdit(){
        let newObj = {RelBookUseInKey:this.state.newItem, CollectionForUseInKey: this.state.displayObj.CollectionForUseInKey, CollectionNumber: this.state.displayObj.CollectionNumber, Rating: this.state.displayObj.Rating};
        //this.props.handleSingleSaveEdit();
        console.log(newObj);
        let newState = update(this.state, {newItem: {$apply: function(x) {return x +1;}}, isEditing:{$set:false}, displayArray:{$push: [newObj]}});
        this.setState(newState, ()=>{console.log(this.state)});
    }
    handleDoNotSaveEdit(){
        let newObj = {RelBookDoNotUseInKey:this.state.newItem, CollectionForUseInKey: this.state.displayObj.CollectionForUseInKey, CollectionNumber: this.state.displayObj.CollectionNumber, Rating: this.state.displayObj.Rating};
        //this.props.handleSingleSaveEdit();

        let newState = update(this.state, {newItem: {$apply: function(x) {return x +1;}}, isEditing:{$set:false}, displayArray:{$push: [newObj]}});
        this.setState(newState);

    }
    handleAwardSaveEdit(){
        let newObj = {AwardKey:this.state.newItem, Award: this.state.displayObj.Award, AwardYear: this.state.displayObj.AwardYear};
        //this.props.handleSingleSaveEdit();

        let newState = update(this.state, {newItem: {$apply: function(x) {return x +1;}}, isEditing:{$set:false}, displayArray:{$push: [newObj]}});
        this.setState(newState);
    }
    handleSingleSaveEdit(){
        let newObj = {id:this.state.newItem, name: this.state.displayText};
        //this.props.handleSingleSaveEdit();
        let newState = update(this.state, {newItem: {$apply: function(x) {return x +1;}}, isEditing:{$set:false}, displayArray:{$push: [newObj]}});
        this.setState(newState);

    }
    handleTextChanged(e){
        //this.props.handleTextChanged();
        this.setState({displayText: e.target.value});
    }
    handleMultipleTextChanged(e){
        //this.props.handleTextChanged();
        this.setState({displayObj: {...this.state.displayObj, [e.target.name]:e.target.value}});
    }
    handleDropSelectChange(value, name){
        this.setState({displayObj: {...this.state.displayObj, [name]:value}});
    }
    handleKeyPress() {
        //this.props.handleKeyPress();
        this.setState({isEditing: !this.state.isEditing});
    };

    onKeyPress(){
        if(event.charCode === 13 && this.props.onKeyPress){
            this.onKeyPress(event);
        }
    }
    handleDelete(e){
    }
    onSelectionHandle( buttonText ) {
        this.setState({displayText: buttonText});
    }
    bindSelectionHandle( buttonText ) {
        return this.onSelectionHandle.bind( this, buttonText )
    }

    drawEntryType(){
        if(this.state.entryType === 'singleText'){
            return <InputContainer className="inputElem" onSaveEdit={this.handleSingleSaveEdit} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} onTextChanged={this.handleTextChanged}/>
        }else if (this.state.entryType === 'awards'){
            return (
                <div>
                    Award:<input name="Award" className="inputValue" value={this.state.displayObj.Award || ''} type="text" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} onChange={this.handleMultipleTextChanged}/>
                        Year:<input name="AwardYear" className="inputValue" value={this.state.displayObj.AwardYear || ''} type="text" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} onChange={this.handleMultipleTextChanged}/>
                <button className="saveMe" onClick={this.handleAwardSaveEdit}>Save</button>
                </div>)
        }else if (this.state.entryType === 'usein'){
            return (<div>
                Collection:<Select
                closeOnSelect={true}
                disabled={false}
                multi={false}
                onChange={(val) => this.handleDropSelectChange(val, "CollectionForUseInKey")}
                options={this.props.collectionOptions}
                placeholder='Select Collection'
                removeSelected={false}
                rtl={false}
                simpleValue
                value={this.state.displayObj.CollectionForUseInKey}
            />
                Collection Number:<input name="CollectionNumber" className="inputValue" value={this.state.displayObj.CollectionNumber || ''}
                                         type="text" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} onChange={this.handleMultipleTextChanged}/>
                Rating:<Select
                closeOnSelect={true}
                disabled={false}
                multi={false}
                onChange={(val) => this.handleDropSelectChange(val, "Rating")}
                options={this.props.ratingOptions}
                placeholder='Select Rating'
                removeSelected={false}
                rtl={false}
                simpleValue
                value={this.state.displayObj.Rating}
                />
                <button className="saveMe" onClick={this.handleUseInSaveEdit}>Save</button>
            </div>)
        }else if (this.state.entryType === 'donot'){
            return (
                <div>
                    Collection:<Select
                    closeOnSelect={true}
                    disabled={false}
                    multi={false}
                    onChange={(val) => this.handleDropSelectChange(val, "Collection")}
                    options={this.props.collectionOptions}
                    placeholder='Select Collection'
                    removeSelected={false}
                    rtl={false}
                    simpleValue
                    value={this.state.displayObj.Collection}
                />
                    Reason:<input name="Reason" className="inputValue" value={this.state.displayObj.Reason || ''}
                                  type="text" onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress} onChange={this.handleMultipleTextChanged}/>

                    <button className="saveMe" onClick={this.handleDoNotSaveEdit}>Save</button>
            </div>)
        }else if (this.state.entryType === 'license'){
            return (<div>

            </div>)
        }
    }
    renderList(){

        if (typeof this.state.displayArray === "undefined"){
            return;
        } else if(this.state.displayArray){
            return this.state.displayArray.map((option)=>{
                return(
                    <Button eventKey={option.value} onClick={ this.bindSelectionHandle( option.text )}>{option.text}</Button>
                );
            });
        }

    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div className="display-choices">
                {this.state.isEditing ? this.drawEntryType() :''}
                <span className="clickMe" onClick={this.onClickEdit}><ArrayList collection={this.props.collectionOptions || []} items={this.state.displayArray} isEditing={this.state.isEditing} /> </span>
            </div>
        )
    }
}export default ArrayValuesEdit;
```

I also have the following connected redux component which holds the ArrayValuesEdit component. In the interest of keeping the code short I will remove the jsx I have written for it, that is not really applicable to why the re-render is happening.

```
export class BookDetail extends Component{
    componentDidMount(){

        Moment.locale('en');
        momentLocalizer();
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(typeof this.props.getAbeReadingLevelOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getAbeReadingLevelOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getAgeAppropriateOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getAgeAppropriateOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getAgeOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getAgeOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getBindingTypeOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getBindingTypeOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getCitationOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getCitationOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getCollectionOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getCollectionOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getCultureOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getCultureOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getDistrictApprovalOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getDistrictApprovalOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getEthnicityOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getEthnicityOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getFormatOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getFormatOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getGenderOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getGenderOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getGuidedReadingLevelOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getGuidedReadingLevelOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getIsbnSeparationStatusOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getIsbnSeparationStatusOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getLexileCodeOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getLexileCodeOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getNarratorOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getNarratorOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getPrimaryGenreOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getPrimaryGenreOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getRatingOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getRatingOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getSecondaryGenreOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getSecondaryGenreOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getSensitiveContentOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getSensitiveContentOptions();
        if(typeof this.props.getCountryOptions !== 'undefined')this.props.getCountryOptions();
    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
        const { match: { params } } = this.props;
        if(typeof this.props.selectBook !== 'undefined'){
            if(this.state.changedItem !== this.props.goToBook ){
                this.props.selectBook(params.bookID);
                this.state.changedItem = params.bookID;
            }

        }
    }
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            isEditingAll: false,
            displayMeta:false,
            displayISBN:false,
            displayPrice:false,
            displayOps:false,
            displayLevel:false,
            displayTrain:false,
            displayAppro:false,
            displayLang:false,
            displayNYC:false,
            displayNotes:false,
            displayTopics:false,
            changedItem:0
        };

        this.onClickMeta = this.onClickMeta.bind(this);
        this.onClickISBN = this.onClickISBN.bind(this);
        this.onClickPrice = this.onClickPrice.bind(this);
        this.onClickOps = this.onClickOps.bind(this);
        this.onClickLevel = this.onClickLevel.bind(this);
        this.onClickTrain = this.onClickTrain.bind(this);
        this.onClickAppro = this.onClickAppro.bind(this);
        this.onClickLang = this.onClickLang.bind(this);
        this.onClickNYC = this.onClickNYC.bind(this);
        this.onClickNotes = this.onClickNotes.bind(this);
        this.onClickTopics = this.onClickTopics.bind(this);
        this.onImgError = this.onImgError.bind(this);
        this.removeSpaces = this.removeSpaces.bind(this);
        this.onCheckChanged = this.onCheckChanged.bind(this);
    }

    onClickMeta(){this.setState({displayMeta: !this.state.displayMeta});}
    onClickISBN(){this.setState({displayISBN: !this.state.displayISBN});}
    onClickPrice(){this.setState({displayPrice: !this.state.displayPrice});}
    onClickOps(){this.setState({displayOps: !this.state.displayOps});}
    onClickLevel(){this.setState({displayLevel: !this.state.displayLevel});}
    onClickTrain(){this.setState({displayTrain: !this.state.displayTrain});}
    onClickAppro(){this.setState({displayAppro: !this.state.displayAppro});}
    onClickLang(){this.setState({displayLang: !this.state.displayLang});}
    onClickNYC(){this.setState({displayNYC: !this.state.displayNYC});}
    onClickNotes(){this.setState({displayNotes: !this.state.displayNotes});}
    onClickTopics(){this.setState({displays: !this.state.displayNotes});}

    onImgError(e) {
        e.target.src = '/img/NoImageFound240px.jpg';
    }
    removeSpaces(val){
        return val.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
    }

    onCheckChanged(e){
        let newVal;
        {e.target.checked ? newVal =  1 : newVal = 0};
        newVal === 1 ? this.setState({isEditingAll: true}) : this.setState({isEditingAll: false});
        this.setState({isEditingAll: newVal});

    }

    render(){
        const YES_NO = [{"value":-1, "label":"N/A"},{"value":0, "label":"No"},{"value":1, "label":"Yes"}];
        if(!this.props.book){
            return <div>Select a book to get started.</div>;
        }
        return(
            ......jsx is added here.....
        )
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return{
        getAbeReadingLevelOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getAbeReadingLevelOptions, dispatch),
        getAgeAppropriateOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getAgeAppropriateOptions, dispatch),
        getAgeOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getAgeOptions, dispatch),
        getBindingTypeOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getBindingTypeOptions, dispatch),
        getCitationOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getCitationOptions, dispatch),
        getCollectionOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getCollectionOptions, dispatch),
        getCultureOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getCultureOptions, dispatch),
        getDistrictApprovalOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getDistrictApprovalOptions, dispatch),
        getEthnicityOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getEthnicityOptions, dispatch),
        getFormatOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getFormatOptions, dispatch),
        getGenderOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getGenderOptions, dispatch),
        getGuidedReadingLevelOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getGuidedReadingLevelOptions, dispatch),
        getIsbnSeparationStatusOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getIsbnSeparationStatusOptions, dispatch),
        getLexileCodeOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getLexileCodeOptions, dispatch),
        getNarratorOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getNarratorOptions, dispatch),
        getPrimaryGenreOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getPrimaryGenreOptions, dispatch),
        getRatingOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getRatingOptions, dispatch),
        getSecondaryGenreOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getSecondaryGenreOptions, dispatch),
        getSensitiveContentOptions: bindActionCreators(actions.getSensitiveContentOptions, dispatch),
        selectBook: bindActionCreators(bookActions.selectBook, dispatch),
        getCountryOptions: bindActionCreators(getCountryOptions, dispatch)
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return{
        options: state.options,
        book: state.activeBook,
        goToBook: state.goToBook
    };
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BookDetail);
```

Comment: You are correct that a component should only rerender when its props (or state) change. So if it is continually rerendering, it's likely that its props are continually changing. Is your redux store continually changing? How is this component connected to redux?

Comment: I added in the parent component in case that helps anyone diagnose a big anti-pattern.

Comment: Are you using redux here?

Comment: On the whole project I am. I am using it to reach out to ajax with apis I built, I am then populating those reducers and making them available to another parent component. I have a few levels of components drawing from each other. Maybe I need to check the nextProps for all of my redux reducers to make sure they are only dispatching when I need them to. I will add code from my parent.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely it is because  you are binding it in render. This will create not only multiple instances of function objects in runtime, every time render is called for outer function. If Button is a Pure component which it should most likely be, every time the Button is re-rendered it will create a new function object reference for onClick and since Buttons prop is changing because it's reference is it will re-render

```
  onClick={this.handleDelete.bind(this, item)} //bad practice
```

do below instead, this will make sure all the onClick refer to one function object reference which is bound in constructor and hence making your component more performant.

```
Constructor(){
this.handleDelete= this.handleDelete.bind(this)
}

//bind it once use every where 
onClick={this.handleDelete}
```

and remove binds in onClicks.

Comment: I took out the bind calls from the delete buttons. But that had little effect on the component re-render. I am checking different props now to see if anything is stuck in an update somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with a mixture of componentDidMount and componentWillReceiveProps to figure out if the new route is hit and the redux selectBook is set or not. Seems to be working now without constant refresh.